# SAS: How export more table in a Excel sheet

Tags: excel, function, sas, export

I am in trouble with the following question: In general, I generate a lot of excel folder with SAS and I export each single dataset to another excel file, in order to have a lot of dataset with 2 columns that is the space between each dataset.

There exist a command in SAS that give to me a single excel file, considering a lot of dataset? For example, if I have 3 dataset in SAS, is possible to have the following output, with some command, as the picture below?

My desired output
[image]

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: ODS EXCEL + START_AT() suboption. You may need to do some math to determine that dynamically if needed.

Comment: Can you write some SAS command, please?

Comment: I was mistaken, it appears you can only control that for the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Reeza notes, this is not possible with the `ODS EXCEL` package.  `ODS HTML` can do this though, sort of:

```
ods html file="c:\temp\test.xls";

ods layout gridded columns=2;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods region;
proc print data=sashelp.class;
run;
ods layout end;
ods html close;
```

However, that's not supported in `ODS EXCEL`.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! And how can I export this in excel?

Comment: That makes a file that excel can read. Before the days of ODS EXCEL it was one of the ways we made excel files. You would then have excel open the file and Save As…; you can automate that if you want using various scripting options including inside SAS using DDE (very much outdated now) or more likely using a power shell script.